# Blazor parameter, how to set array length

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In a child component I have:

```
[Parameter]
public bool[] ShowHideDetail {get;set;}
```

In my parent form I have:

```
@foreach (var reviewers in Reviewers)
{
    <childComponent ShowHideDetail=xxxxxx></childComponent>
}
```

Where Reviewers contains 2 recordsets, of different lengths.
I want to be able to do something like:

```
<childComponent ShowHideDetail= new bool[@reviewers.Length]>
```

but I cant. Can anybody see how I could do this? I also pass in the reviewer recordset to the child component. I tried setting the length in the OnInitializedAsync Function of the child component, but this only gets fired the first time, so when I swap recordsets via the parent, the OnInitializedAsync no longer fires. Placing in the OnAfterRenderAsyc on the child form also fails.

What I really need is a pre-render, but this doesn't seem available. I am using Blazor Web Assembly.

Comment: Are you asking how to instantiate a bool array of certain length where all values are set to true? Because passing that array to `ShowHideDetail` is not a problem.

Comment: See my "Answer" below.  On your `OnInitializedAsync` section you need to show some code.  Use my "minimum reproducible" example below as a template.

Comment: @GSerg My understanding is that bool is set to false by default. The Trouble is  Passing 'new bool...' seems to be an issue for Blazor. Can you Show the syntax I should be using when setting the parameter, because with 'new' ir wont even compile

Comment: @bilpor In any way you like? E.g. `ShowHideDetail="new bool[reviewers.Length]"`? `ShowHideDetail=@(new bool[reviewers.Length])`?

Comment: @GSerg THanks, yes, I was doing the first option and it complained about the use of 'new' doing the second example you have given, has solved my issue. I would be happy  to mark this as the correct answer if you want to make it an answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @bilpor You were not doing the first option, you were missing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimum reproducible version of your question that works as expected.  Where is your code different?

Component:

```
<h3>BoolComponent</h3>

@foreach(var boo in ShowHideDetail)
{
    <div>
       Answer =  @boo
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] [EditorRequired] public bool[] ShowHideDetail { get; set; } = { true };
}
```

And page:

```
@page "/BoolPage"
<h3>BoolPage</h3>

<BoolComponent ShowHideDetail=bools></BoolComponent>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.Swap">Swap Recordet</button> 
</div>

@code {
    private bool[] bools = { true, true,false };

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        var questions = rand.Next(1, 10);
        // Emulate a data get
        await Task.Delay(10);
        bools = new bool[questions];
    }

    private async Task Swap()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        var questions = rand.Next(1, 10);
        // Emulate a data get
        await Task.Delay(10);
        bools = new bool[questions];
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to set the length of the array from the parent.

Comment: See my updated answer.